# Razorpay Django Integration with Callback URL (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

Tags: python, django, razorpay

I am trying to Class Based View with Razor Pay, Everything working Perfectly. But When i am POST data too same view it is giving error `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /buy-coin`.

I am having two question here

1. How we can exempt CSRF Token for post method
2. In Razorpay Javascript Code, can we add `csrf` token in callback url.

Razorpay Python Integration Link - https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/server-integration/python/

View.py

```
class BuyCoinPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=("scretKey", "secretKey"))
        data = { "amount": 10000, "currency": "INR", "receipt": "order_rcptid_11" }
        payment = client.order.create(data=data)
        print('Razor Pay - ', payment['id'])
        return render(request, "pricing-page.html", {'payment': payment})
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST
        print(data)
        return render(request, "pricing-page.html")
```

HTML FILE

```
<a href="#" id="rzp-button1" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_hwAkAHZlKJdgee", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
    "amount": "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Acme Corp",
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
    "order_id": "{{payment.id}}", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
    "callback_url": "{% url 'buy_coin' %}",
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
        "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        "contact": "9999999999"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3399cc"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Terminal Logs -

```
[08/Nov/2021 15:22:12] "GET /static/assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 27172
[08/Nov/2021 15:22:12] "GET /media/exam-logos/Java-logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 38915
Razor Pay -  order_IJ9ngRpV19pdEc
[08/Nov/2021 15:22:16] "GET /buy-coin HTTP/1.1" 200 8478
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /buy-coin
[08/Nov/2021 15:22:37] "POST /buy-coin HTTP/1.1" 403 2519
```

[image: Browser Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

write a function for your call_back and do a csrf exempt

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def razorpay_call_back(request):
   "write your code here"
```