# Integrating Razorpay Payment Gateway with Django causing CSRF verification failure

Tags: python, django, razorpay

*This question was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886006/razorpay-django-integration-with-callback-url-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect) but I didn't have 50 reputation points to continue the discussion on that answer itself.*

**Short version**

Essentially, the problem boils down to - I have an external URL that sends POST data to my Django application. I want to access this POST data but Django is giving 403 error (CSRF Token missing).

**Detailed version**

I am trying to add [Hosted Payment Gateway](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/web-integration/hosted/build-integration/) of Razorpay to my Django Project. I have passed the URL to the following function in the callback functionality.

As specified in the previous answer, I tried using the `csrf_exempt` decorator and adding the `https://api.razorpay.com` URL as `CSRF_TRUSTED_DOMAINS` in the `settings.py` file, but the issue still remains. I am still getting the 403 error from Django when the payment is successful.

```
@csrf_exempt
def course_purchase_callback(request):
    payment_id = request.POST.get("razorpay_payment_id")
    order_id = request.POST.get("razorpay_order_id")
    signature = request.POST.get("razorpay_signature")
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=(os.getenv("RZP_ID"), os.getenv("RZP_SECRET")))
    verify = client.utility.verify_payment_signature({
        "razorpay_payment_id": payment_id,
        "razorpay_order_id": order_id,
        "razorpay_signature": signature,
    })
```

settings.py file

```
..
..
..
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://api.razorpay.com"]
..
..
```

Versions being used:

- Django = 4.0.3
- Razorpay API = 1.3.0

What is the thing I am missing here?

Comment: Hello @Japkeerat Singh I mean can you provide your callback url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this issue was resolved a while back.

The solution was to add `@csrf_exempt` tag on the function that was initiating request to Razorpay gateway and not the function that would accept the request from the payment gateway.